# Anyone have experience with Javascript old-school winamp embed player?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

What i want to load a custom .wsz skin on page-load on my website.
I still don't understand how to do it to make it work.
Here a snippet with my code:
https://codepen.io/cat999/pen/rNOOjJP

js

```
const webamp = new Webamp({
    initialTracks: [{
        metaData: {
            artist: "DJ Mike Llama",
            title: "Llama Whippin' Intro",
        },
        url: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/captbaritone/webamp/43434d82/mp3/llama-2.91.mp3",
        duration: 5.322286,
    }],
})

webamp.onMinimize(() => {
  const webampEl = document.getElementById('webamp')
  webampEl.style.display = 'none'
})

webamp.renderWhenReady(document.getElementById('app')).then(() => {
  document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    const webampEl = document.getElementById('webamp')
    webampEl.style.display = 'none'
  })

  document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const webampEl = document.getElementById('webamp')
    webampEl.style.display = 'block'
  })
})
```

Here below the skins I would like to see on my page-load

https://srv-file6.gofile.io/download/KwUySB/Aphex_Twin_-_Windowlicker.wsz

Anyone could help on How I should improve my js code to make It work?

Comment: why do you mark this as Java? Java and JavaScript are not related

Comment: The skin file you linked to does not seem to be available. Is it this one? https://webamp.org/?skinUrl=https://s3.amazonaws.com/webamp-uploaded-skins/skins/dbaead7a819b238d48ca726abd0617bb.wsz

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Initialization portion of the docs?

https://github.com/captbaritone/webamp/blob/master/docs/usage.md#initialize-the-javascript

Try constructing Webamp by adding an `initialSkin` option:

```
const webamp = new Webamp({
    initialTracks: [{
        metaData: {
            artist: "DJ Mike Llama",
            title: "Llama Whippin' Intro",
        },
        url: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/captbaritone/webamp/43434d82/mp3/llama-2.91.mp3",
        duration: 5.322286,
    }],
    initialSkin: {
        url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/webamp-uploaded-skins/skins/dbaead7a819b238d48ca726abd0617bb.wsz"
    },
})
```